# Video content type is invalid in paperclip-ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip

When I try to upload .mov video in paperclip-ffmpeg it gives an error

> Video content type is invalid in paperclip-ffmpeg

My code is

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => { 
:medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'webm' }
}, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
validates_attachment_size :video, :less_than => 100.megabytes
validates_attachment_presence :video
validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mov"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `video/quicktime` as the mimetype. Have a look at a list of video mimetypes overhere:

http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/